# php-cs-fixer not working on mac after update

Tags: php, macos, php-cs-fixer

I ran `php-cs-fixer self-update` on a Mac machine and `php-cs-fixer` stopped working. No output returned (even with `--verbose`). Files stay unchanged. I tried reinstalling it (used all possible install options). Tried running with `sudo`. Still nothing happens. Before update it worked, and now it just does not. Version is 2.3.2 now. Unfortunately, I do not know what version was prior to update. How do I fix my `php-cs-fixer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it was a corrupt `.php_cs` file in the root of the project. I renamed the file and php-cs-fixer started working